# How to handle many different look-up references and avoid hard-coding in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database-design

Most of my experience has been with smaller projects and anytime I needed to create a look-up table I actually made a new table, even if it just contained a few entities.

I'm starting on a slightly larger project now, and in planning the database I can foresee at least several dozens of look-up tables. Furthermore, I'm looking at how I can avoid hard-coding into the database schema as much as possible, such that new types of look-ups might in the future be added through the application rather than the database schema.

For example, say I have a product table with 25+ columns describing attributes of each product. In my application, many of the attributes will be modified using drop-downs or check boxes. In order to populate these fields I would use look-up tables.

I'm wondering if it's commonplace or good practice to actually create a new table for each look-up, or if there is a better way, such as creating one table with an additional column to distinguish what attribute the look-up is referring to. What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no universal "best way" to do this. Several dedicated tables - ok. One larger table with discriminator field is also fine.

It seems that you'll have to go with the second option, because of your requirement ("I want to be able to add new lookups without altering DB schema").

Just index that discriminator column and you're good to go (assuming that your values are all of the same type (strings, for example)).